# Minkowski functional of a convex set is a convex function.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a real vector space, and $K$ be a convex set with $2$ properties:
$0\in K$ and $\forall x\in X, \exists t >0$ s.t. $x/t\in K$.

Define the Minkowski functional of the set $K$ to be $p_K(x)=\inf \{t>0: x/t\in K \}$. Show that  $p_K(x)$ is convex.

I have tried for some while using the definition of a convex function, but failed to prove this fact. Any idea on how to show it?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you need the further property that $x\in K\Rightarrow -x\in K$?

Comment: @charlestoncrabb We don't have this property in this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Try to show Triangle Inequality first.